# How to Enable Migrations in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

`PM> enable-migrations
The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ enable-migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

i am getting this error when ever i want to enable migration 
i tried:`Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease`,`Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Comment: Sems you don't have entity Framework installed, go to "managed packages installed" in right click solution and check for it.

Comment: Put your Entity Framework version, please.